# simple canvas animate circle using jquery vs setInterval(function(){}

Tags: jquery, canvas, jquery-animate, geometry

I'm use to using Jquery animation but do I need it to draw canvas circle? I noticing a lot of setInterval(function(){} to trigger the draw function but is this the only/best way of archiving this?

Comment: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jCanvas](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/index.php):

```
// Draw a circle on the canvas
$("canvas").drawArc({
  fillStyle: "black",
  x: 100, y: 100,
  radius: 50
});
```

Comment: some good information I didn't know about .JCanvas. What I'm trying to do is create a circle price range that can be draggable. See here: http://widgets.better2web.com/loader/

Comment: I'm guessing if I add Jquery animation to code above to have the circle automatically draw on screen.

Comment: I believe I can use animateLayer() for this please let me know if I'm wrong because I'm going in on this project now.